# Convert string to date in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to convert a date string to `time` (dd/mm/yyyy) but I am getting this error -

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 parsing time "29/12/2020": month out of range
```

Here is my code - https://play.golang.org/p/X99jId-cI0U

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your layout is `mm/dd/yyyy`, if you want `dd/mm/yyyy` switch the two values.

Comment: Use layout  `02/01/2006`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the date layout in your sample code should read `"02/01/2006"`.